# Apache POI- SXSSFWorkbook - Block a row from flushing

Tags: apache, excel, apache-poi

I have a scenario where i am creating a very large xlsx files using SXSSF workbook(around 1-2  million).

- While writing to the sheet , i have to dynamically populate some values say Headers only in Row 1 of the sheet

PROBLEM:
 Since its streaming api , if i am in 100000 th row ,and wanted to populate some value in Row1, by this time my Row 1 got flushed out and try to write its not available.

Questions:
1. can i block any row from flushing?
2. Any solution you can think of?

I am thinking to hold the Row1 values , flush the whole workbook, read in the workbook again, create the Row1 and flush again.

Better solution Please ....

Comment: Buy some more memory for your server, then use the regular `XSSFWorkbook` which allows full read/write access to the whole workbook at the same time?

Comment: :)  yes we can,but now  we don't have the provision to increase. any ideas pl?

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, you can't. SXSSF is a streaming writer for the file format. Once a set of rows have passed out of the buffer, they are written to disk, into a file format that requires ordering. At that point, they're gone, and can't be changed, as other things have come after them.

If you need full read/write access to the whole workbook, then you need to switch to the fully featured `XSSFWorkbook`. That buffers everything in memory, so you can change any parts you like for as long as you want, as it only get sequenced out when write the file.

`XSSFWorkbook` does need more memory than `SXSSFWorkbook`, since it keeps the whole file in memory. You'll probably need to bump up your heap size. For most things though, memory is much much cheaper than programmer, so just chuck some more RAM at it!

Comment: Solution incase any one need it:                                              - To keep the memory footprint low, no ram increase, not using XSSF    - Instead of writing to an XLSX we are writing to .csv file initially and while actually creating the .xlsx we are writing the header row and copy the records from .csv to .xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

Solution incase any one need it: - To keep the memory footprint low, no ram increase, not using XSSF - Instead of writing to an XLSX we are writing to .csv file initially and while actually creating the .xlsx we are writing the header row and copy the records from .csv to .xlsx file.